# 'list' objet is not callable when defining python function

Tags: python

I am trying to create a function composite to:
1)count how many times each character appears in the string; 
2)pass the result to a dictionary with pairs of character and occurrence time; 
3)and find out which character has the most occurrences

For function `best_key(dictionary)` I keep getting the error message ('list' object is not callable). Does anyone know why?

```
def count_frequency(st):
    d = {}
    for c in st:
        if c not in d:
            d[c] = 0
        d[c] = d[c]+1
    return d

def best_key(dictionary):
    ks=dictionary.keys() 
    best_key_so_far = list(ks)[0] **TypeError: 'list' object is not callable**
    for k in ks:
        if dictionary[k]>dictionary[best_key_so_far] 
            best_key_so_far=k
    return best_key_so_far


def final_one(s):
    freq=count_frequency(s)
    return best_key(freq)

print(final_one("567tfgffffbbbbb"))
```

Comment: IndentationError - please fix.

Comment: You probably shadow the list() built in - check your code for an assignment `list = .....`

Comment: I can't reproduce this error (I've only assumed where the indentation is, so I guess that could be affecting it...)

Comment: Correct indentation and in the best_key method add a colon to the if condition, works for me

Comment: The problem is not the logic, it is the indentation

Comment: Yes I actually made two mistakes, 1) the indentation 2)passed a list in previous codes with the name 'list', thus python is confused. Problem solved and thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked your code, and it turns out it contains one or more syntax error.
Here is the correct code:

```
def count_frequency(st):
    d = {}
    for c in st:
        if c not in d:
            d[c] = 0
        d[c] = d[c]+1
    return d


def best_key(dictionary):
    ks = dictionary.keys()
    best_key_so_far = list(ks)[0]
    for k in ks:
        if dictionary[k] > dictionary[best_key_so_far]:
            best_key_so_far = k
    return best_key_so_far


def final_one(s):
    freq = count_frequency(s)
    return best_key(freq)
```

And when you call,

```
print(final_one("567tfgffffbbbbb"))
```

The output will be,

```
f
```

Hope it helps you!

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer, you can accept the answer as a correct answer and mark the question as completed.

Answer (score 0):

f and b both are appearing 5 times so answer should be ['f','b']. You can use below code for same.

```
def count_frequency(st):
    d = {}
    for c in st:
        if c not in d:
            d[c] = 0
        d[c] = d[c] + 1
    return d


def best_key(dictionary):
    MaxValue = max(dictionary.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])
    listOfKeys = list()

    for key, value in dictionary.items():
        if value == MaxValue[1]:
            listOfKeys.append(key)
    return listOfKeys


def final_one(s):
    freq = count_frequency(s)
    return best_key(freq)


print(final_one("567tfgffffbbbbb"))
```

The output will be

```
['f', 'b']
```